# Troubleshooting .NET Binding Redirects in Publisher Policy Files

Tags: .net, gac, fusion, assembly-binding-redirect

How can you trouble-shoot exactly why an **Assembly Binding Redirect** from a **Publisher Policy File** is not being followed? (Fusion is showing me that it's NOT, but not WHY)

Background

- Microsoft SharePoint makes extensive use of [assembly binding redirects](http://sadomovalex.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/assembly-binding-redirect-in-sharepoint.html) between versions e.g. v12.0 (SharePoint 2007) > v14.0 (2010)
- Suddenly on one particular server, this has stopped working. (usual Windows updates, but so have other servers, no other changes of note I *think*). Still working on supposedly identical machines.

Digging out [Fusion Log Viewer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer) shows where this IS working (cut down for brevity)

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry ***
...
The operation was successful.
...
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
LOG: Publisher policy file is found at C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Policy.12.0.Microsoft.SharePoint\14.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Policy.12.0.Microsoft.SharePoint.config.
LOG: Publisher policy file redirect is found: 12.0.0.0 redirected to 14.0.0.0.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c, processorArchitecture=MSIL
```

On the server that IS NOT working

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry ***
...
The operation failed.
...
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
```

Both servers have the policy file in the GAC as shown with gacutil -l

```
Policy.12.0.Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c, processorArchitecture=MSIL
```

Answer (score 0):

Not answering the question as such which was "How to troubleshoot [further than the info Fusion gives you]" but this is what I did to solve this particular problem.

Found a copy of the Publisher Policy File assembly at

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Policy\Policy.12.0.Microsoft.SharePoint.dll
```

Removed it from the GAC with

```
gacutil /u Policy.12.0.Microsoft.SharePoint
```

Reinstalled with

```
gacutil /i Policy.12.0.Microsoft.SharePoint
```

Works immediately.

No idea what broke it in the first place though.